# не работает кнопка возврата на основной экран

Tags: java, android

ошибка в  two.java

```
btnActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActOne);  <identifier> expected
btnActOne.setOnClickListener(this);  illegal start of type
```

**main activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to Activity Two"
        android:id="@+id/btnActTwo">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnActTwo;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnActTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActTwo);
        btnActTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnActTwo:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

**two.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Activity Two">
    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to Activity One"
        android:id="@+id/btnActOne">
    </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

**ActivityTwo.java**

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button btnActOne;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.two);
    }

    btnActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActOne);
    btnActOne.setOnClickListener(this);


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnActTwo:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: закрывающая фигурная скобка метода должна быть, собственно, в конце метода. Две строчки в которых ошибка не относятся ни к одному методу и выполняться не будут.

Comment: В `ActivityTwo `вы пытаетесь интентом перйти в нее же, когда хотите, видимо в `MainActivity`. Во второй активити надо так - `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);`. Стоит заметить, что правильно этот вопрос решается через стек переходов, а не прямым вызовом активити.

Answer (score 1):

В OnCreate нужно эти две строчки

```
btnActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActOne);
btnActOne.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Так:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.two);

    btnActOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActOne);
    btnActOne.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

А вот с кнопкой назад, думаю будет второй вопрос)

Comment: компилится но кнопка не работает

Answer (score 1):

Прислушайся совету выше и в классе `ActivityTwo` нужно поменять строку

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
```

на

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

а вообще это бесполезно, просто нажми на кнопку "Назад" и перейдешь в первое активити. [вот тут можешь почитать об этом](https://habrahabr.ru/post/186434/)